# Is $\cos(\ln(x))$ transcendental?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

I am aware that according to Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem:

1) $\sin(a),\;\cos(a),\;\tan(a)$, and their multiplicative inverses $\csc(a),\;\sec(a),$ and $\cot(a)$, for any nonzero algebraic number $a$, the result will be transcendental.

2) $\ln(a)$ if $a$ is algebraic and not equal to $0$ or $1$ will also be transcendental.

However, if you put any value (except $1$) for $x$ in $\cos(\ln(x))$, according to Wolfram Alpha, the result will be transcendental.

I would like to know why that is so. Does anyone have a proof that every value of that function will be transcendental? (if that is the case)

Comment: You ask, "does anyone have a proof that every value of that function will be transcendental?". You might want to refine this question. The function $x \mapsto \cos(\ln x)$ is continuous, $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \cos(\ln \varepsilon) = -1$, $\cos(\ln 1)$ is positive, so the function has a zero on the interval $(0,1)$. Zero is not transcendental.

Comment: Obviously $\cos(\ln(z)) = 0$ where $z = e^{\pi/2}$.  I hope the question is whether $\cos(\ln(x))$ is transcendental where $x$ is **algebraic** and not $1$.

Comment: I see those points, I will edit the question. My point, though, is that if x=5, for example, we have that, from rule 2, the value will be transcendental. However, when the cosine of this value is taken (cos(ln5)), this result is also transcendental. My doubt is that rule 1 makes no mention of these cases (since this rule only mentiones algebraic numbers), which happen with almost every value of x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\exp(i \ln(x)) = x^i$ (for a suitable branch).  Since $i$ is algebraic and not rational, the Gelfond-Schneider theorem says that $\exp(i \ln(x))$ is transcendental whenever $x$ is an algebraic number other than $0$ or $1$.  And from that you can get that $\cos(\ln(x))$, $\sin(\ln(x))$, $\tan(\ln(x))$ are also transcendental.

Comment: What is the meaning of "for a suitable branch"? Thank you!

Comment: @manooooh $x^i$ is a multivalued function over the complex numbers.

Comment: Yes. If $z$ is an integer, the natural logarithms of $e$ are of the form $1+i2z$